# Rxjs buffer when source emitions rate is fast

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

let's say for instance I have an observable emiting at x0 emitions per second (maybe 50, 60, ...) sometimes and sometimes it's just 1 or 2 emitions per second.

Now how can I Buffer those fast emitions and still handling slow ones.

What I tired:

BufferTime needs a time span, so even if one emition it will be bufferd, (plus BufferTime makes protractor tests timeout).

BufferCount(x) doesn't emit until all x emitions are received.

Comment: Are you describing this: Hold an emit for X time and if another emit comes in before X expires then buffer them. Buffer up to a maximum time of Y or until an emit doesn't come in before X (whichever is first). So slow emits would be delayed X and fast emits would be delayed as little as X and as much as Y. Basically the debounce operator for buffering.

Comment: I don't understand where's the problem

Comment: @martin as bygrace said something like debounce but for buffering (i.e that returns the values as array and not ignore them )

Comment: It sounds like you could use `bufferTime(time, null, size)`. This buffers at most `size` items OR any lower number of items for at most `time`.

Comment: Or you could use `source.buffer(source.debounceTime(X))` so that it will buffer till a debounce would execute. It would help if you could provide a practical example of messages passing through the stream with their times and your expectations of how they would be buffered.

Comment: @bygrace Thanks. My practical example would be in the ag-grid library. I emit a vlue each time a cellValueChanged event fires, and when a user copy pastes mutiple 100 cells, this would fire 100 cellValueChanged events. If you put your solution down I would accept it

Comment: @RachidOussanaa I put an answer up. Let me know if it does what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want something similar to debounce + buffer. The simplest implementation of that is to use a debounce of the stream to trigger emiting the buffer of that same stream. You may want to share the stream to prevent duplicate subscriptions. Here is a running example:

```js
const source = new Rx.Observable.create((o) => {
  let count = 0;
  const emit = () => {
    const timeout = Math.random() * 1000;
    setTimeout(() => {
      o.next(count++);
      if (count < 20) {
       emit();
      } else {
        o.complete();
      }
    }, timeout);
  };
  emit();
}).share();

const triggerBuffer = source.debounceTime(500);
source.buffer(triggerBuffer).subscribe((x) => { console.log(x); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.9/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Note that the debounce does not have an upper limit in that it wont emit if it continues to receive values under the debounce time. Practically this shouldn't make a difference in your scenario but in other scenarios it theoretically could.

Answer (score 0):

As bygrace mentioned, what you are looking for is `debounce + buffer`

In modern RXJS 6 and with ES6 Typescript to add type inference, I created a custom OperatorFunction to do that very straightforward, called **`bufferDebounce`**.

```js
type BufferDebounce = <T>(debounce: number) => OperatorFunction<T, T[]>;

const bufferDebounce: BufferDebounce = debounce => source =>
  new Observable(observer => 
    source.pipe(buffer(source.pipe(debounceTime(debounce)))).subscribe({
      next(x) {
        observer.next(x);
      },
      error(err) {
        observer.error(err);
      },
      complete() {
        observer.complete();
      },
  })
// [as many sources until no emit during 500ms]
source.pipe(bufferDebounce(500)).subscribe(console.log);
```

you can see a working example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-buffer-debounce

Hope this helps to you and any newcomers.